# Can't apply background image in css (flask template)

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to apply background image in internal css. I'm using flask template. this is my directory

```
src - templates - image - img.jpg
src- templates - upload.html
```

I want to apply the background image at upload.html. but I got 404 error. can someone help me please?

my code:

```
background-image: url("/image/img.jpg");
```

error message:

> get /image/img.jpg HTTP/1.1 404

Comment: use background-image: url("/templates/image/img.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

I think you are giving wrong path and that's why you are getting 404 error.You can use following code.

```
background-image: url{"image/img.jpg"};
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple issues like :

1. Incorrect directory-URL: Try specifying the whole URL - instead of `"/image/img.jpg"` try `"/templates/image/img.jpg"`.
2. Misspelled directory-name - check it properly.
3. Reassure yourself that the specified image is in the correct format (`.jpg`).

Answer (score 1):

The (Flask) standard way of doing this, which you'll see done in examples and tutorials, is to put static files in a `static` folder at the root of the project. Assuming your CSS is also in `static`,

```
background-image: url('/static/img.jpg');
```

does what you want. But if you're embedding styles in templates,

```
background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='img.jpg') }});
```

is preferred, though the former will work just fine.

If things get more complicated and you start using blueprints, consult the documentation.

Comment: "background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='img.jpg') }});"  is this supposed to be used in the css file or the between the style tags?

Comment: In a style attribute in a template

Comment: u mean the style tag??

Comment: Ah, you could either put that in a `<style>` tag in a template, or you could use it as the value of a `style` attribute on some element (in the template). Which ever works better for you.